# Is there a name for this type of polygon?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Is there a name for a polygon in which you could place a light bulb that would light up all of its area? (for which there exists a point so that for all points inside it the line connecting those two points does not cross one of its edges)

Examples of "lightable" polygons:

[image]

Examples of "unlightable" polygons:

[image]

Comment: I fail to see how the second is not "lightable"? The first one also seems to just be lightable but it depends on the exact size.

Comment: @Runemoro: the second seems to consist of two overlapping triangles. As a triangle is convex, it is entirely lit by any point inside it, so putting the point in the tiny area where the triangles overlap should lit the entire figure.

Comment: Similarly the first seems to be three triangles, if the top of the lower triangle is high enough to be inside the right triangle.

Comment: For the "lightable" polygons, the possible locations you can put the lightbulb and still light the whole interior [is called the kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-shaped_polygon).

Comment: They are the polygons for which the [_Art Gallery_ number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem) is 1.

Comment: [Are the unlightable polygons really not star-shaped? They both appear to have kernels which are line segments.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2IkiQ.png)

Comment: Since it is easy to cook up a shape which is clearly not lightable (e.g. an annulus), I wonder whether all the comments objecting that _these particular_ shapes are lightable are really worthwhile.

Comment: @DanielWagner yes, I think the comments are worthwhile.  I for one had a faulty understanding of "lightable polygons based on the diagrams.  The diagrams should be corrected or removed.

Comment: I've uploaded a corrected version of the diagram.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Yes, those are called [star-shaped polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-shaped_polygon). They have numerous applications in mathematics, for example in complex analysis.

Answer (score 27):

More generally, such a set is a [star domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain), and is a trivial example of [contractible space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space).

You may see this as a generalization of a [convex set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set): indeed,

- $C\neq\emptyset$ is a **convex domain** if for every $x,y\in C$ you have that the line segment $\overline{xy}\subseteq C$ is contained in $C$; while
- $S\neq\emptyset$ is a **star domain** if there exists a point $y$ such that for every $x\in S$ it holds that $\overline{xy}\subseteq S$.

That is, in a star domain the point $y$ (there might be many such) is fixed. You can easily prove that a set $E\neq\emptyset$ is convex (actually [simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space)) if and only if it is a star domain with respect to each *center* $y\in E$.

Answer (score 14):

I think you are looking for [star domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain). See also [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182346/what-polygons-can-be-shrunk-into-themselves/182349#182349) on Mathoverflow.